How to get Neutralinojs to work after sleep on windows 11
I am fairly new to Neutralinojs and so far I am fairly impressed but I have a problem in that when I have a Neutralino app running and I put the windows 11 pc to sleep, although it is still visible when I re-awaken the pc everything is frozen.
I understand, although I know nothing about it, that Neutralino uses Webview2. Is it possible that the problem is there. If so how do I fix it. The same app running without Neutralino but using a Chrome browser works perfectly fine after waking up.
I don't know what to try to fix it and I was expecting the app to work on re-awakening the pc.

After much searching I finally found an answer myself that seems to work. Check this out: https://github.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs/issues/1021.   Neutralino.events.on("serverOffline",function(){
var date = new Date();
var timestamp = date.toLocaleString('en-US');
console.log('server offline ' + timestamp );
window.location.reload();
}); This worked for me in Windows 11

Good solution, works for me. btw.: why don't you write your findings in a answer, and accept your own answer. like your solutions is easier to read, your question is marked as solved, AND you might even earn a sweet Stackoverflow Badge. :)
